# Loading empty dictionary when YAML file is empty (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a YAML file that is empty, and when I load it in, I would like to load it in as an empty dictionary. For example, I have

```
import yaml
with open('an_empty_file.yml', 'r') as config_file:
    config=yaml.load(config_file)
    print(config) 
None
```

It turns out that `yaml.load(config_file)` will return a `NoneType` object, which I suppose makes sense. Is there an easy way to just return an empty dictionary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it returns `None`, you can just use `or` so your config will hold an empty dictionary by default if `yaml.load` returns None:

```
config = yaml.load(config_file) or {}
```

Ultimately, what is happening here, starts from the left hand side:

We are right now assigning a value in to config. We are stating to assign `yaml.load(config_file)` in to config, however, by using the `or`, what we are saying in this statement is that, if it (`yaml.load`) evaluates to a None or False condition (i.e. In this case for us, None), we will then assign `{}` to config.

Quick demo taking an empty string as config_file:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> config_file = ''
>>> config = yaml.load(config_file) or {}
>>> print(config)
{}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It did solve the problem, but I am a little confused. I am familiar with the usage of `or` as a boolean operator, but I don't quite understand why it works here.

Comment: I'll gladly explain. Updating answer.

Comment: Interesting. So `None` and `False` are the same/similar?

Comment: @Vincent . This is where we have to be careful. They are not the same at all, but they evaluate to the same *false* condition. If you do `if None == False: print('stuff')`. You will not see stuff. Or even `if None is False: print('asdf')`. 'asdf' will not be outputted.

Comment: This is good for many use cases but see @Anthon 's answer for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

At the top level a YAML file can have

- a mapping, indicated by key value pairs separated by `:` (optionally in flow style using `{}`),
- a sequence indicated by `-` if it is block style and `[  ]` if it is flow style
- a (single) scalar.

Your file is not a mapping or a sequence, so it is a scalar and since the scalar with an empty representation is considered to be the same as specifying

```
null
```

in the file.

To load this as an empty dictionary and not as None you can do:

```
with open('an_empty_file.yml', 'r') as config_file:
    config = yaml.load(config_file)
    config = {} if config is None else config
    print(config)
```

You should **never** try and take a short cut of doing:

```
config = yaml.load(config_file) or {}
```

as this would also cause files with the single scalar `0`:

```
0
```

with single scalar floats `0.0`:

```
0.0
```

with hex scalars `0x0`:

```
0x0
```

with an empty double quoted scalar `""`

```
""
```

with an empty single quoted scalar `''`

```
''
```

with an empty folded scalar:

```
>
```

with an empty literal style scalar:

```
|
```

with the single boolean `False`:

```
False
```

or `no` ¹:

```
no
```

or `off` ¹:

```
off
```

as well as the empty sequence:

```
[

]
```

to result in `config` to be an empty dictionary.

The number of different file contents that would be incorrectly changed to empty dictionaries is endless.

---

¹ This is a result of PyYAML never been updated for 1.1 to the 1.2 standard published in 2009. If it would be it would also convert octals of the form `0o0`.